# If a random variable is bounded by a constant with high probability, is its expectation also bounded by the same constant with the same probability?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, bounds

Suppose $X$ is a random variable that is bounded with high probability, i.e., $|X| < M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with probability $1-p$. Is it correct to say that $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<M$ with probability $1 - p$ as well?

Comment: Since E(|X|) is not a random variable, that statement does not make a good sense.

Comment: What does "bounded by a constant with high probability" mean?  I can think of two interpretations, one of which allows this question to make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable such that:

$$
P(X=0)=0.999\\
P(X=1000000)=0.001
$$

Also, let $M=1$.

Then $P(\vert X\vert <M)=0.999$, which I say counts as a high probability. However, $\mathbb E[X]=1000>1$.